# An odd, cryptic error from libgdx's version of box2d involving a mousejoint

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

[Code](http://pastebin.com/wShV23Dt)

There is my code for my `Screen` object. The garble of arrays and `Vector2`s at the bottom is just a long list of models for the cats. My goal is to make a port of http://catsinspace.co.nf, my website, to learn how to use libgdx and its box2d port. I am trying to get the mousejoint working, but I apparently don't understand how a `groundBody` is supposed to work, despite my hours of googling. Here is my strange, cryptic error that I have tried googling fruitlessly:

```
AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/gdx/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2MouseJoint.cpp, Line 125

Expression: d + h * k > 1.19209289550781250000e-7F
```

It pops up when I try to drag the cat, but I can *try* to drag the walls without error.

I figured it out. I'm an idiot. The actual body that you want to be dragged needs to be `bodyB` and not `bodyA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def.bodyA = groundBody;
def.bodyB = callback.body;
def.maxForce = 1000f;
```

This will make it work, though I cannot explain you why...

Comment: Yeah, it's because box2d uses `bodyB` for the assertion calculation involving mass. I looked through the source and found that out. Thanks for the help!